# Flex ItemRender Not Updating Data Source

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, itemrenderer, 2-way-object-databinding

First up sorry the the mass of code and terrible coding, it's been some time since I have done AS3/Flex and for the life of me I can't remember how to get an ItemRenderer inside an ItemRender to update the data source. For example **GymButton2.mxml** simple adds +1 to the data it it provided with when a button is clicked and this should update the original datasource activeGym but... it doesn't and I assume this is because binding is not working as expected?

**Main.mxml**

```
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            public var activeGym:Gym2;

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:DataGroup x="33" y="56" width="200" height="200" dataProvider="{activeGym.sets}" itemRenderer="GymSetRenderer">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout />
        </s:layout>
    </s:DataGroup>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

**Gym2.as**

```
package
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    [Bindable]

    public class Gym2 extends EventDispatcher
    {

        public var sets:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        public function Gym2(target:IEventDispatcher=null)
        {
            super(target);
        }

        public function addSet(set:GymSet):void {
            sets.addItem(set);
        }

    }
}
```

**GymSetRenderer.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="false" xmlns:local="*">

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <s:Label fontSize="27" text="{data.title}"/>

    <s:DataGroup dataProvider="{data.data}" itemRenderer="GymButton2">
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout />
        </s:layout>
    </s:DataGroup>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

**GymButton2.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" autoDrawBackground="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                data = data + 1;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button label="{data}" height="70" click="onClick(event)"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Could you show "GymSet" class sources?

Comment: if data is just a number it cannot be watched so you'll have to update the data yourself via events. Your itemrenderer can just dispatch an event to request a data update.